# check property when using triggers in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a trigger in my xaml that change the text of a button, when mouse is hover over the button.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Cyan" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

But I want that the colour doesn't changes if the button is disabled. Is there any way that I can check if control is enabled when I am changing the colour on hover on?

**Edit1**

Based on Bolu answer I implemented this multitrigger:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
</MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
 </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
 <MultiTrigger.Setters>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
  </MultiTrigger.Setters>
```

But it is not working properly.
the triggers should change the text colour to red if the button is disable and green if it is enabled. But when the button is disabled, colour doesn't changes to Red, but when button is enabled, it changes to Green.

How can I change the xaml so the disable part works too?

Comment: You must be confused... that code will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The change in look when the control is disabled comes from the default `ControlTemplate` of the `Button`. If you provide your own `ControlTemplate`, as it appears that you are doing, then that should override that change. Alternatively, you can just add a `Trigger` to handle the `IsEnabled` property to provide your own disabled look:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Cyan" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <!-- Put your disabled Style Setters here -->
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: if I put <setter property="foreground" value="Red"/> in IsEnabled trigger, when I disable the control, the text became read, but as soon as I place the mouse over the button, it changes to cyan. How can I stop this is happening?

Comment: Reverse the order of the `Trigger`s.

Comment: How can I change the colour based on the IsEnabled property? For example, OnMouseOver, if control is enabled, change colour to cyan and if control is disabled change colour to red?

Comment: Well that's a different question and involves a [`MultiTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multitrigger(v=vs.110).aspx), but luckily for you @Bolu seems to have answered *that* question rather than your *actual* question in this post.

Comment: That's a pretty poor show my friend... you asked a question that I answered. *Then* you changed the question *after* you had an acceptable answer for it. That's really bad practice on this website.

Comment: Perhaps we can take this as a learning experience this time... either way, Bolu's code *should* do exactly what you wanted... I think that you should try it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`MultiTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.MultiTrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if it is enabled.

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     <MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition  Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>                                            
          </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Cyan" />
     </MultiTrigger>
                                   
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Based on your editing:

I think you could wrap your button in a `panel` and trigger the color using `Panel`'s `IsMouseOver` plus `Button`'s `IsEnabled`.

Comment: @mans, I think your initial question mislead my answer.... I thought you don't want the effect that you can trigger `IsMouseOver` while the button is Disabled. Your edited question shows clearly the opposite: `IsMouseOver` will not be detected when your button is Disabled. So I think you could wrap your button in a `panel` and trigger the color using `Panel`'s `IsMouseOver` plus `Button`'s `IsEnabled`.